# how to get the current month in two languages?

Tags: datetime

from time to time, a current month value has to be updated.

it is a din a4 page, which includes german and english text.
at the end of the page, only the month and year (without a day) is given.

For instance `Jänner / January 2014` (right now)

which LaTeX command / trick can be used to avoid manual month modifications?
(when using pdflatex, the 2 month values and the year should be up to date without a modification but in german and english --- as stated in the example above)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would define my own translations, which also allows you to predict the output. Below `\monthGermanEnglish` conditions on `\THEMONTH` (provided by [`datetime`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime)) and prints the [appropriate German translation](http://german.about.com/library/anfang/blanfang12b.htm):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}% http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\monthGermanEnglish}{%
  \ifcase\THEMONTH
  \or Januar / January% 1
  \or Februar / February% 2
  \or M\"arz / March% 3
  \or April / April% 4
  \or Mai / May% 5
  \or Juni / June% 6
  \or Juli / July% 7
  \or August / August% 8
  \or September / September% 9
  \or Oktober / October% 10
  \or November / November% 11
  \or Dezember / December% 12
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\verb|\today:| \today \par
Month: \monthGermanEnglish
\end{document}
```

Comment: that avoids much headache & some update effort. Danke / Thanks