# Expl3 command that inserts spaces between letters?

Tags: macros, expl3

I want to make an `expl3` command that puts a space (`~`) between letters, and makes every letter uppercase.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

    % \NewDocumentCommand \addspaces { m }
    % Some code

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The command \verb|\addspaces{helLo9   $\Delta$  @}| should produce: \\
 
H E L L O 9 $\Delta$ @

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: I want it to work inside this environment:

```
\makebox{} \\
{\centering
  \fontsize{0.023753\paperwidth}{0.023753\paperwidth} \makebox[\textwidth][s]{ \bfseries 
  {\scshape \addspaces{\the\month} \ \  \addspaces{\the\year}  \ \ \addspaces{edition} }}
\par}
```

But with @Skillmon 's answer I get this:

[image]

Comment: Please, make a complete specification. You have an example where there's text interspersed with “backslash-space” commands, but then your example of usage just applies `\addspace` to single parts. Some clarification is needed.

Comment: are you maybe looking for microtype's `\textls` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task can be solved without Expl3 too:

```
\def\addspaces#1{\uppercase\expandafter{\expandafter\addspacesA#1\end}}
\def\addspacesA#1{\ifx#1\end \else #1 \expandafter\addspacesA\fi}
```

Of course, you don't have to upgrade your TeXlive 2022 because only TeX primitives are used here and they are more than 40 years in TeX.

Comment: I have a command for displaying the month in another language like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153775/199568 . Do I need some extra ``\expandafter`` to be able to use this command inside ``\addspaces``?: ``\addspaces{\monthGermanEnglish}``? Currently i get an error.

Comment: Yes, the macro supposes only single expand step because you show its usage for `\the\month`. If your macro ` \monthGermanEnglish` is fully expandable then you can try to use `\expanded` primitive, for example `\def\addspaces#1{\uppercase\expandafter{\expandafter\addspacesA\expanded{#1}\end}}` Moreower, you need to use luatex or xetex in order to be correct `\uppercase` of März.

Comment: Unfortuantley that did not work. I get no errors, but also no output.

Comment: You can test, if the macro is expandable, by `\message{\monthGermanEnglish}`. I am unable to do this test because I don't know where the `\monthGermanEnglish` macro is defined.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. It worked with the definition I had, but not the example I gave. It worked in the end.

Answer (score 4):

The following produces the output you show in your question.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__vebjorn_text_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \addspaces { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nx \l__vebjorn_text_tl { \text_uppercase:n {#1} }
    \tl_remove_all:Nn \l__vebjorn_text_tl { ~ }
    \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \vebjorn_gobble_space:w
      { \text_map_function:nN \l__vebjorn_text_tl \__vebjorn_addspaces_aux:n }
  }
\use:n { \cs_new:Npn \vebjorn_gobble_space:w } ~ {}
\cs_new:Npn \__vebjorn_addspaces_aux:n #1 { ~ \exp_not:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The command \verb|\addspaces{helLo9   $\Delta$  @}| should produce:
 
H E L L O 9 $\Delta$ @

Proof:

\addspaces{helLo9   $\Delta$  @}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get 4 errors and the output ``ELLO9∆@`` running your exaple. I use TeX live version 2022.  The errors are: 1) ``Undefined control sequence. \text_map_function:nN `` 2) ``Argument of \__vebjorn_addspaces_aux:n has an extra }.`` 3) ``Runaway argument? ! Paragraph ended before \__vebjorn_addspaces_aux:n was complete.`` 4) ``Use of \vebjorn_gobble_space:w doesn't match its definition.``

Comment: @Vebjorn update your TeXLive.

Comment: I use Overleaf and there is no newer version than TeXLive 2022.

Comment: @Vebjorn then I'm sorry, the two functions to iterate through text were added to `l3text` on 2022-08-04. I'm afraid there is no viable solution that works in all engines and respects Unicode in Overleaf yet. Use either an offline installation which supports this, or one of the other answers, but be aware of their limitations.

Answer (score 3):

I know the request was for an expl3 approach.  However, the `tokcycle` package can also provide this behavior using 2e syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\addspaces[1]{%
  \tokencycle
  {\addcytoks{\uppercase{##1}}%
   \tcpeek\z\ifcat A\z\addcytoks{~}\else
   \ifcat 0\z\addcytoks{~}\fi\fi}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}#1\endtokencycle
}

\begin{document}

The command \verb|\addspaces{helLo9   $\Delta$  @}| should produce: \\
 
H E L L O 9 $\Delta$ @

\addspaces{helLo9   $\Delta$  @}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a big difference in the `tokcycle` behaviour to the `expl3` one using the `l3text` module, though: Try the input `\addspaces{helälo}` for instance in pdfTeX.

Comment: @Skillmon True...using `tokcycle`, proper output is only achieved with xelatex and/or lualatex for the case you cite.